# Do i need to buy a license or copyright the content like wallpaper, audio etc before using it in my app?

Tags: android, wallpaper

Do i need to buy a license or copyright the content like wallpapers before using it in my app.

Currently i am working on an app which mainly deals with wallpapers and i am thinking to use wallpapers which i have downloaded from the internet for free. So i was wondering that do i need to buy its license from its owner? as its available for free on internet or can i use it freely in my app?.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make it?  No?  Then you can't use it unless you have an agreement with whoever *did* make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its always must to ask the artist before you use their artwork. Some of image you use have some sort of license associated with it. Like for example on devianart has its [information page giving details about the copyright](http://about.deviantart.com/policy/copyright/).

If no such page is avaliable, try contacting the artist. Most of them will gladly promote their work through your app for free, with the clause that you should mention and link their page.